# CountRows on a measured column based upon specified value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a measured column that has different values. Now I am creating a measure to display on a card which should compare a specified value to all rows of the calculated column and give a count.

I tried the following but it is not working and showing blank:

```
Table1[Asia] =
VAR oAsia = CALCULATE ( [Avg] + ( [stdv] * 3 ) )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), FILTER ( 'Table1', Table1[Asia] > oAsia ) )
```

Table1[Asia] is giving the sum of all values of the calculated column instead of the individual row value.

```
Retailers  Asia  USA
------------------
A          1    5
B               6
C          2    7
D               2
E          3    3
F               1
G          4    4
```

Comment: Can you give us the source table and some test data?

Comment: Please check my original post. I have edited and added example. Retailers  column is coming from database. Asia and USA are calculated columns

Answer (score 0):

Set the properties of the field in the Table visual to "Do Not Summarise"

[image]

Comment: I don't see this property on calculated columns.

Comment: Have you accidentally created your calculated column as a measure ?

Comment: No , Asia column comes from measure

Comment: Then it is a measure not a calculated column. https://insightsoftware.com/blog/calculated-columns-vs-measures/

Comment: A measure is not a column. It's a calculation that can have a column or any related table's column or any aggregation as context that influences the result. Please provide samples of all tables and the relationships in your model.